# Standard way to measure linear regression input variable "strength"?

Tags: regression, feature-selection, regression-coefficients, weights

Doing a work project where I created a simple multivariate linear regression model in python with sklearn. My model performs well, now I'd like to discuss some takeaways with my team, namely the "weight" or "strength" of each input variable.

I have the coefficient matrix from sklearn, and I understand the coefficients represent change in output per unit change (1) in input but my concern is my input variables are not normalized. Some have range [0,1], others have range [0,10000].

To me (and maybe I am mistaken), a variable with a coefficient of 100 with range [0,1] is more "important" to study than a coefficient of 0.1 with range [0,100]. It may be worth mentioning that the input variables are fairly uniformly distributed in their ranges. Is there a standard method for what I am describing here, or am I trying to fix a non existent problem and the coefficients are telling enough?

Thanks

Comment: The only way I thought about doing this was to multiply the coefficients by the DV's standard deviation, range, or other metric, but I suspect there is a standard way to do this.

Comment: @Glen_b thanks for pointing out my mistake, meant IV, but changed it to input variable for more clarity

Answer (score 1):

You should have gone for normalisation/standardisation of variables before you fit the model. This gives better interpretability of the coefficients and also helps the parameters to converge faster."To me (and maybe I am mistaken), a variable with a coefficient of 100 with range [0,1] is more "important" to study than a coefficient of 0.1 with range [0,100]". This statement of yours is right. The feature has less variability [0,1] but still has high coefficient.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Does normalization of input variables effect model results? It seems that normalizing them shouldn't change anything, right?

Comment: I general it wont but if you are using gradient decent type algorithm for convergence then normalisation will speed up the process. Model results are not effected